# Change wording “Login to add this product on shopping list.” when viewing item on Magento sites

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I am wanting to change "Login to view your price" to “Login to add this product on shopping list.” that is currently displayed.

[Screenshot where the text is on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WllUB.png)

Answer (score 0):

This message is not part of default Magento.
Probably you've installed a third party module or made some customisations to prevent guest customers from adding products to the cart.

First step you can take is to find the message in your code base. You can search the string in your IDE (e.g. in PhpStorm with double pressing Shift).
Or from command line from project root: `grep -r 'Login to add this product on shopping list' *`

After this you can determine if you can change the string directly or need an override in a custom module.